# Complexity of Quicksort

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursion

I am currently struggling with a problem on time complexity of the Quicksort algorithm in the average case.

I calculated the average time complexity of the algorithm to be

$T_n \quad = \quad \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \left( T_{k-1} + T_{n-k} + n - 1 \right)$

Which can also be written as

$T_n \quad = \quad n - 1 + \frac{2}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n T_{k-1}$

So far so well; now I have to calculate the term:

$n\cdot T_n - (n-1)\cdot T_{n-1}$

and solve the outcoming linear recursion of first order.

My ansatz is to insert the upper equation into this term, which gives me

$n\cdot T_n - (n-1)\cdot T_{n-1} \quad = \quad n^2 - n + 2 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n T_{k-1} - \left[ (n-1)(n-2) + 2 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T_{k-1} \right]$

Whereof I get

$n\cdot T_n - (n-1)\cdot T_{n-1} \quad = \quad 2 \cdot \left[ (n-1) + T_{n-1} \right]$

Now, I am stuck. Because if I solve the equation for $T_n$, I obtain

$T_n \quad = \quad \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left[ (n+1) T_{n-1} + 2(n-1) \right]$

This is not linear though, meaning I made a mistake somewhere, or there is another way to solve this.

Does anyone have an idea how to carry on or how to solve this?

Sincerely,
Octavius

Comment: You should look at Cormen et al.'s book. It is well written with probability.

Comment: I already checked the chapter about quicksort, but did not really find something I could use to solve my problem. Did I miss the woods for the trees?

Comment: How did you set up the recursion for the average case?

Comment: For the (randomised) quicksort I have (n-1) comparisons with the pivotelement, after that, I call the quicksort recursively  for each of the two parts. So let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be an arbitray number within the intervall $[1,n]$, then the time complexity is:

$T_n = (n-1) + T_{k-1} + T_{n-k}$ .

Since all $k$ are equally likely (probability $\tfrac{1}{n}$) to be chosen as the random pivotelement I have to sum over all cases multiplied with the corresponding probability, which finally gives me:

$T_n = (n-1) + \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n T_{k-1} + T_{n-k}$

Comment: That is the hard way, see page 181 on the third edition.

Comment: Thank you for your effort so far. The thing is though, that this is a problem I have to work on for university. The task for me to fulfill is to 1.) set up the recursion the way I did above, which is as you said probably less simple to solve, and 2.) to "calculate the term $\left( n \cdot T_n - (n-1) \cdot T_{n-1} \right)$ and solve the outcoming linear recursion of first order".
So even though I understand the way Cormen et al. used in their book, I still have to calculate it alternatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it down. I start from the above mentioned term

$n \cdot T_n \quad = \quad  (n+1) \cdot T_{n-1} + 2(n-1)$

Since I only want to know magnitudes and asymptotic behavior I simply discard the $-2$ term, remaining with

$n \cdot T_n \quad = \quad  (n+1) \cdot T_{n-1} + 2n$

which is equivalent to

$\frac{T_n}{n+1} \quad = \quad  \frac{2}{n+1} + \frac{T_{n-1}}{n}$ .

Basically I am done now, because all I have to do is recursively insert the equation:

$\frac{T_n}{n+1} \quad = \quad  \frac{2}{n+1} + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{T_{n-2}}{n-1} \quad = \quad \frac{2}{n+1} + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{2}{n-1} + \frac{T_{n-3}}{n-2} \quad = \quad \text{etc.}$

In a more compact form:

$\frac{T_n}{n+1} \quad = \quad 2 \cdot \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}$

Which is the $(n+1)$-th partial sum of the harmonic series, meaning

$\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \quad \in \quad O(\log n)$

In conclusion:

$ T_n \quad \in \quad O(n \cdot \log n)$

That is what I wanted to find as a solution in agreement with relevant literature solutions.